# How to make a Jframe containing a Jpanel scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

So I have this JFrame that contains a JPanel and in there I add JLabels with information I want but since I'll be adding labels all the time at some point the text is too long to appear so I want to add a scrollbar. Basically I want to make my JFrame with a JPanel in it scrollable. I have this code but my problem is that even though the scrollbar appears but it doesnt move and doesn't really work when the text is a lot, meaning the text still gets cut out and the scrollbar is there not moving. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Bar {
JFrame info = new JFrame("Information");
JLabel ballinf = new JLabel();
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrolling = new JScrollPane();

public Bar(){
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    scrolling = new JScrollPane(contentPane,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    info.add(scrolling);
    info.setSize(750, 600);
    info.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    info.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    info.setVisible(true);
}

public void adding(int pos){       
    ballinf = new JLabel("Something ",JLabel.CENTER);//assume the text will be bigger here and have more info
    ballinf.setSize(700, 30);
    ballinf.setForeground(Color.green);
    ballinf.setLocation(5, 5+pos);
    contentPane.add(ballinf);

    info.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    info.setVisible(true);
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Bar stats = new Bar();
    stats.adding(0);
    stats.adding(20);//this will be done in a for loop for more than 2 times so the text ends up to be a lot
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout!!!

You need to use an appropriate layout manager. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. The layout manager will then determine the preferred size of the panel as you add components to the panel.

The scrollpane will then display the scrollbars when necessary.

If you dynamically add components to the panel (after the GUI is visible) then the code should be something like:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: should revalidate and repaint be called?

Comment: @helpme, did you try it?

Comment: @DarkV1 `should revalidate and repaint be called?` - I stated the condition under when those methods should be called.

Comment: just did the scrollbar does work thank you so much! however now that I no longer have the Layout to null the structure of the text is gone.. meaning before i made the position was right with this command `ballinf.setLocation(5, 5+pos);` but all the information ends up on the same line? do you know how to fix that? sorry to ask another question in this one.

Comment: @helpme, I already told you the solution. You need to use an appropriate layout manager. The default layout is a FlowLayout. I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial on layout managers. Read the tutorial and use the appropriate combination of layout managers. You have to read if you want to be a programmer.

Comment: @DarkV1,`we should just suggest answers that are the best practice? Not work on the user's current code if its following a bad practice?` - you need to understand the context of the question. The OP thinks using a null layout is a good idea, but doesn't understand why it is a bad idea. There are many reason why it is a bad idea. For one, scrolling doesn't work. So we should try to point out the problems with the current design and suggest better alternatives. Don't let them learn and keep using bad habits.

Comment: @camickr sorry I was focused on the scrollbar and didnt notice your link. thank you it was very helpful and I get a bit more about all the layouts now!